# How to remove duplicates leaving only one

Tags: postgresql

I want to add a unique constraint on a table, eg

```
ALTER TABLE report ADD UNIQUE (date, scholar_id);
```

Each scholar should have only one report per day and the application checks whether there is an existing report for the scholar for the date but due to having a cluster of servers I occasionally do get duplicates.

Now I need to remove aproximately 700 items from the table.

I run a query like

```
SELECT date, scholar_id, count(*) 
FROM report 
GROUP BY date, scholar_id
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

And see about 548 rows.  Some with counts = 3 or 4, most with count = 2.

These "duplicates" cause the ALTER TABLE to fail.

I am hoping to automate deleting these duplicates (all except 1 per scholar_id/date pair).

I imagine some way to get the pairs, and then per pair get all the rowids, and then DELETE FROM report WHERE id = any(...) AND NOT id = any(... limit 1);

Note: it is not important which one of the copies are removed.  There are other columns and the other columns might not have identical values.

How to do this is the question...

Comment: Do you have any unique column (like a `serial`) in that able?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3777633/330315

Comment: Yes there is a UUID primary key. `rowid`

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need.  but min(rowid) doesn't work on UIDs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12963112/330315

Comment: Another option is to simply cast the rowid to text: `min(rowid::text)`

Comment: This worked perfectly, though I had to also cast the column to text in the left side of the condition in the where statement.  If you would turn that into an answer I would gladly accept it.